# LingPipe POS tagger runs out of memory

Tags: java, memory, nlp, pos-tagger, lingpipe

I'm having trouble using the [LingPipe POS tagger](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/posTags/read-me.html) to count the most frequently used parts of speech in a large (~180MB) corpus of e-mails. Specifically, it consumes enormous amounts of memory (at least 4GB), such that no matter how much memory I give the JVM it fails with an OutOfMemoryError. Before I give up and try a different tagging library, I thought I'd ask to see if anyone here was familiar enough with LingPipe to know what I'm doing wrong.

I start by reading a HiddenMarkovModel object in from the file pos-en-general-brown.HiddenMarkovModel, included with the LingPipe library, which is boilerplate Java serialization code. Then I try to use it like this:

```
HmmDecoder decoder = new HmmDecoder(hmm, new FastCache<String, double[]>(1000),
    new FastCache<String, double[]>(1000));

List<Email> emails = FileUtil.loadMLPosts(new File(args[1])); 
Multiset<String> rHelpTagCounts = countTagsInEmails(decoder, emails);
```

Where `countTagsInEmails` is defined as follows:

```
static TokenizerFactory TOKENIZER_FACTORY = IndoEuropeanTokenizerFactory.INSTANCE;

public static Multiset<String> countTagsInEmails(HmmDecoder decoder, List<Email> emails) {
    Multiset<String> tagCounts = HashMultiset.create();        
    for(Email email : emails) {
        char[] bodyChars = email.body.toCharArray();
        Tokenizer tokenizer = TOKENIZER_FACTORY.tokenizer(bodyChars, 0, bodyChars.length);
        List<String> bodyTokens = new ArrayList<>();
        tokenizer.tokenize(bodyTokens, new ArrayList<String>()); //Throw away the whitespaces list, we don't care
        Tagging<String> taggedTokens = decoder.tag(bodyTokens);
        tagCounts.addAll(taggedTokens.tags());
    }
    return tagCounts;
}
```

I don't think the deetails of `FileUtil.loadMLPosts()` are important; this just creates a list of `Email` objects from my 180MB e-mail archive file, where the `body` field of each `Email` is a String containing the e-mail's body. Note that the `Multiset` is Guava's implementation.

If I watch Java's memory usage while running my program, it starts at 1GB (already surprisingly high), then steadily climbs the more e-mails are tagged. At a few points it jumps dramatically, by several hundred megabytes at once. Before it can finish tagging the corpus, it reaches 4GB (the amount of memory I gave my JVM) and crashes.

Is LingPipe's HmmDecoder supposed to be this memory-inefficient? Or am I using it wrong? I notice that the example given on LingPipe's (rather sparse) documentation page for POS tagging always shows the decoder tagging one sentence at a time, so is it a mistake to pass the entire e-mail body to `decoder.tag()`?